# Integrating NetLogo and Java : when should we think about this integration as a good option?

Tags: netlogo

I just came to know about this excellent tutorials

http://scientificgems.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/integrating-netlogo-and-java-part-1/
http://scientificgems.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/integrating-netlogo-and-java-2/
http://scientificgems.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/integrating-netlogo-and-java-3/

Their example concerns about computation needed for patch diffusion and shows how to access patch variable from java and change them in netlogo.

I was wondering if anyone has any idea or comments on when we should think of writing an extension to make our model work better? I am new to netlogo itself, but I think it's good to know what are the options that I might not be aware of  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think looking through the extensions listed at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions , both the ones that we (on the NetLogo team) have built ourselves and the ones that have come from the user community, gives you a pretty good idea of the range of things extensions can be good for.

Some broad categories:

- data structures (tables, arrays, matrices, priority queues...)
- algorithms (networks, statistics, discrete event scheduling, diffusion, ...)
- integration with other tools (R, SQL databases, MatLab, ...)
- media (sound playback, sound synthesis, images, movies, speech, ...)
- new device types (Gogo, Arduino, WiiMote...)
- visualization (ray-tracing, sprites, Java2D drawing, ...)

not necessarily exhaustive!