# Is it possible to write NetLogo simulation programs in Java?

Tags: java, netlogo

I am trying to develop NetLogo model (consumer research), but I would like more control over what agents (turtles) are and what they can do, therefore I would like to write code in Java, import Java libraries, possibly, use rules engine and so on. Is that possible in NetLogo?

If not, then what other agent modelling frameworks with Java programming capabilities are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible with NetLogo using the [Extensions API](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API). With this API, you write your overall model in NetLogo, making calls into your Java-based routines as needed. (You cannot call a Java library directly from NetLogo code; rather, you write an extension that exposes the routines in that library as NetLogo primitives, and then you use those primitives in your model.) A look at the [NetLogo extensions download page](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions) should give you an idea of the diverse sorts of things are possible with this API.

See also: [Integrating NetLogo and Java : when should we think about this integration as a good option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20558780/86485).

Two notable agent-based modeling frameworks where you write your entire model in Java are [Repast](http://repast.sourceforge.net) and [MASON](http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/mason/).